# How to render a RABL template in a view template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I am using RABL for formatting a JSON API response. However, I would like to use that same JSON and render it inline in a different view to use with some JavaScript. Essentially, I'd like to do:

```
var my_model_data = #{@model.to_json}
```

...but use the RABL template instead of calling `to_json`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, based on [this wiki post](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Backbone-Integration).

Instead of:

```
@model.to_json
```

You can do this:

```
render(file: 'foo/bar', object: @model, formats: :json).html_safe
```